# How to install ioncube Loader on openshift

Tags: openshift, ioncube

I'm having a problem activating ioncube on openshift.

The loader-wizard tells me to do the following steps:

1) Download one of the following archives of Loaders for Linux x86-64: zip tar.gz tar.bz2 etc.

2)Transfer the Loaders to your web server and install in /usr/lib64/php/modules

3) Put this: "zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so " in your ini files directory, /etc/php.d

4)Restart the Apache server software. When the server software has restarted, click here to test the Loader. If the Loader installation failed, check the Apache error log file for errors and see our guide to Unix related errors.

But I can't transfer the loader in /usr/lib64/php/modules, because I don't have permissions.

I tried to put the loader somewhere else and edit the new php ini located at ~/php/versions/shared/configuration/etc/php.ini I added there the the path to the loader, restarted the app, but still does not work.

I also posted this question on openshift.com forums, but didn't get any answers at the moment.
Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Success in Loader installation will ultimately depend on the server and PHP configuration.

ionCube have recently released a Windows based installer that can automatically deploy the required Loader locally or to a remote server over FTP or SFTP, and also make configuration file changes. I suggest trying that. The download is at http://ioncu.be/LI

(disclosure: I am associated with ionCube)